# Hadoop Pig Cassandra get_range_slices error

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cassandra, apache-pig

I'm using Cassandra 1.0.9 and the latest Pig and Hadoop to execute MapReduce tasks.

Just a simple task scripted in Pig to extract 2 columns from the Cassandra database.

Seems to work and then it encounters this problem.

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing get_range_slices at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$RowIterator.maybeInit(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:334) at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$RowIterator.computeNext(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:348) at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$RowIterator.computeNext(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:222) at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.tryToComputeNext(AbstractIterator.java:140) at com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:135) at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader.nextKeyValue(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:178) at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.pig.CassandraStorage.getNext(Unknown Source) at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigRecordReader.nextKeyValue(PigRecordReader.java:194) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67) at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Internal error processing get_range_slices at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:108) at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_get_range_slices(Cassandra.java:754) at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.get_range_slices(Cassandra.java:734) at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader$RowIterator.maybeInit(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:289) ... 17 more

Is there a way around it? I could show the Pig script on request.

Comment: The first thing you should do is check the Cassandra logs to see what the internal error was.

Comment: Hmm ok. How do i prevent RPC timeouts in this case?

Thanks Jonathan Ellis! :)

Comment: You'll find the RPC timeout setting in cassandra.yaml, which is either in $CASSANDRA_HOME/conf or /etc/cassandra if installed using a package manager.